# How get Start or End Point ModelLine

Tags: c#, api, revit

I'm new in Revit Api and i need help.
I have some ModelLine. 
How do o know the starting or ending point of the ModelLine?

```
Selection mySelection = rvtUIDoc.Selection;
        ICollection<ElementId> selectedIds = rvtUIDoc.Selection.GetElementIds();

        ICollection<ElementId> selectedlinesIds = new List<ElementId>();

        foreach (ElementId id in selectedIds)
        {
            Element elements = rvtUIDoc.Document.GetElement(id);

            if (elements is ModelLine)
            {
                selectedlinesIds.Add(id);
            }
        }

        //Проверяем есть ли выделенные объекты
        if (0 == selectedlinesIds.Count)
        {
            TaskDialog.Show("Revit","Вы не выделили ни одной линии");
        }
        else
        {

            ModelLine(rvtUIDoc, m_rvtDoc, selectedlinesIds);
        }
```

what i must do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a newbie to the Revit API, I would suggest you work through the Revit API getting started material first of all, especially the DevTV and My First Revit Plugin tutorials:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2

That actually answers this question and many more.

The direct answer to your question is: the ModelCurve start and end points are controlled by the underlying geometry curve.

It can be accessed via the `GeometryCurve` property.

It provides the `GetEndPoint` method that returns the 3D point at its start or end.

That answers your question.

To define a new start or end point, i.e., modify the existing one, you might need to create an entirely new curve.

Here is an example of doing exactly that:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/08/generating-a-midcurve-between-two-curve-elements.html